# Is it possible to generate a compile-time error if some member function hasn't been called

Tags: c++, c++11, singleton

I'm coding a class with Singleton pattern.

```
class GroupListDAO {
public:
    static GroupListDAO* getInstance() {
        static GroupListDAO groupListDAO;
        return &groupListDAO;
    }

    init(server::mysqldb::MysqlHelperTempalte* pHelper) {
        mysqlHT = pHelper;
    }

    bool getUserHeartNum(uint32_t owner, uint32_t& totalNum);
    bool setUserHeartNum(uint32_t owner, uint32_t totalNum, uint32_t update_time);
private:
    MysqlHelperTempalte *mysqlHT;

    GroupListDAO() = default;
    ~GroupListDAO() = default;
};
```

As you see, this class is used to connect to Mysql. So the member data `mysqlHT` must be initialized before calling any other member functions.

In a word, the class user must use this class as below:

```
GroupListDAO *p = GroupListDAO::getInstance();
p->init(XXX);    // init must be called before calling any other member functions
p->getUserHeartNum(...);
p->setUserHeartNum(...);
```

So I'm thinking if there is a way to force the class user to call the function `init`. Meaning that if the class user codes like this:

```
GroupListDAO *p = GroupListDAO::getInstance();
p->getUserHeartNum(...);
p->setUserHeartNum(...);
```

Some compile-time error can be generated.

Ofc, you might say that we can `if (mysqlHT == nullptr) { throw exception; }` in other member functions, but that would be runtime error, instead of compile-time error.

**REAL CASE**

One large project is developed by 5 developers. They are all using some Singleton objects. But they must say: Hey, I've initialized that, you guys can use it in your codes. Or, we are sorry, we all forget to initialize it...

Comment: why is `init` not called in `getInstance` as part of initialization?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number  You see, I don't want to call `getInstance` with any parameter. `getInstance` could be called many times, right? If `getInstance` needs some parameter, I don't think it's a good design.

Comment: I understand, and I faced same issue several times. Nevertheless I think it could be more explicitly mentioned in the quesiton.

Comment: public `init` functions are not good design either.  Singletons leave a thing to be desired as well.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number  Saying that you are the class user. I think you would like to do the initialization only once, after that you can use it anywhere. When you use it, you don't want to remind yourself that "OK, I should pass xxx to `getInstance`". Besides, pass parameter to `getInstance` is kind of stupid because the parameter would be used only the first time of calling `getInstance`.

Comment: `getInstance(server::mysqldb::MysqlHelperTempalte* pHelper = nullptr)`

Comment: I understand ;) It could be an optional parameter, with a default, thats also not perfect, because allowing the caller to pass a parameter that is only used on the first call isnt nice either

Comment: I think the fundamental flaw in the design is that "not knowing who first calls `getInstance`"  is part of the singleton" but your are trying to work against that.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Yes. The project of my company is quite large, there are so many low-level/util-like classes, such as `DAO`. Many of them are designed with Singleton. For now some of them have to call `ClassName::init(...)` in the function `main`. Developers often forget to do that...

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number One project is developed by 5 developers. They are all using some Singleton objects. But they must say: Hey, I've initialized that, you guys can use it in your codes. Or, we are sorry, we all forget to initialize it...

Comment: I posted my 2cents as answer. I'd love to see a better solution.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number  Good one. Let's see if there is a better solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested in a comment, you can use an argument with a default:

```
getInstance(server::mysqldb::MysqlHelperTempalte* pHelper = nullptr)
```

On the one hand it isnt nice to let the caller pass the parameter but using it only on the first call. On the other hand your design suggests that there is one place where you know it is the first call to `getInstance` (you don't want to `init` it twice, right?). Hence I propose this:

```
class GroupListDAO {
public:
    static GroupListDAO* createInstance(server::mysqldb::MysqlHelperTempalte* pHelper) {
        return getInstance(pHelper);
    }
    static GroupListDAO* getInstance() {
        return getInstance(nullptr);
    }
private:
    static GroupListDAO* getInstance(server::mysqldb::MysqlHelperTempalte* pHelper = nullptr) {
        static GroupListDAO groupListDAO(pHelper);
        return &groupListDAO;
    }
};
```

`GroupListDAO` perhaps needs to be a wrapper of the actual object and it can throw in its constructor when called with a `nullptr`. I am not aware of an easy way to create a compiler error.

---

PS: Actually I think you have conflicting requirements. On the one hand you want a singleton that hides initialization from the caller. The instance can be obtained via a `getInstance` without needing to care about the initialization. On the other hand you do want to care about initialization because the first call to `getInstance` is "special". Both, the singleton pattern, and using an `init` method, are not perfect idioms in isolation. When used together they are worse. I am not saying that it is an absolute no-go, but it isnt too surprising that a compromise has to be made when both approaches should be kept.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want a compile error, you would have to get rid of your singleton pattern:

```
class GroupListDao
{
public:
  GroupListDao(...) { /* do your initialization here */ }

  bool getUserHeartNum(uint32_t owner, uint32_t& totalNum);
  bool setUserHeartNum(uint32_t owner, uint32_t totalNum, uint32_t update_time); 
  // ...
}
```

This way you ensure that any instance of `GroupListDao` has been initialized. You then would have to pass this instance around in your code. As consequence, you no longer can be sure that there is only one instance of `GroupListDao` in your application at compile time (if you really want you could track the number of created instances in your constructor and raise errors at runtime).
Pick your poison ;)